# Got a `TypeError` when using `np.unique` on a list of objects containing a `datetime` (Python / Numpy)

Tags: python, numpy, datetime

I am trying to use `np.setdiff1d` between 2 python objects, but couldn't manage. I found out that I can't use `np.union` on a list of objects containing a datetime!

To reproduce the error :

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

d = datetime.now()
a = [(1, d), (2, d), (3, d), (3, d)]
np.unique(a)
```

And this throws the following error :

```
  File "<ipython>", line 6, in <module>
    np.unique(a)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py", line 264, in unique
    ret = _unique1d(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py", line 312, in _unique1d
    ar.sort()
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.datetime' and 'int'
```

Is it a bug from numpy ?
Do you know if there's any other way to solve what I'm trying to do (originally willing to use `np.setdiff1d between 2 lists of a similar structure`) ?

In advance, thank you !!

Comment: `unique` turns the list into an array, and tries to 'sort' the elements.  That's why it's trying to do  a `<` test.

Comment: Your opening paragraph mentions `np.setdiff1d`, but your title and example code all involve `np.unique`. The solution may depend on what you're actually asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the reason: `numpy.unique` will flatten the array first. From the documentation:

> Input array. Unless axis is specified, this will be flattened if it is not already 1-D.

So, you have to think along which axis you'd like the elements to be unique (for NumPy, your lists of tuples will look like a 2D array); then use the correct `axis` keyword value. Unfortunately, you'll quickly find that that won't work either, since the elements are regarded as an object (since NumPy tries to mix integers and datetimes into a single object type), which in NumPy don't allow for a comparison.

But since you're using a list of tuples (nothing NumPy there), just use `set()`:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>>
>>> d = datetime.now()
>>> a = [(1, d), (2, d), (3, d), (3, d)]
>>> set(a)
{(2, datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 1, 17, 15, 38, 578611)), (1, datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 1, 17, 15, 38, 578611)), (3, datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 1, 17, 15, 38, 578611))}
```

Note that the set is naturally unordered.